# why does having more than one thread(parallel processing) in some specific cases degrade performance?

Tags: c++, multithreading

i noticed that having more than a thread running for some code is much much slower than having one thread, and i have been really pulling my hair to know why,can anyone help?

code explanation :
i have ,sometimes, a very large array that i need to process parts of in a parallel way for optimization,each "part" of a row gets looped on and processed on in a specific thread, now i've noticed that if i only have one "part",i.e the whole array and a single worker thread that runs through it is noticeably faster than if i divide the array and process it as separate sub arrays with different threads.

```
    bool m_generate_row_worker(ull t_row_start,ull t_row_end)
    {
        for(;t_row_start<t_row_end;t_row_start++)
            {
                m_current_row[t_row_start]=m_singularity_checker(m_previous_row[t_row_start],m_shared_random_row[t_row_start]);

            }
        return true;
    }

    ...
    //code
    ...
    for(unsigned short thread_indx=0;thread_indx<noThreads-1;thread_indx++)
    {
        m_threads_array[thread_indx]=std::thread(
                m_generate_row_worker,this,
                thread_indx*(m_parts_per_thread),(thread_indx+1)*(m_parts_per_thread));
    }
    m_threads_array[noThreads-1]=std::thread(m_generate_row_worker,this,
            (noThreads-1)*(m_parts_per_thread),std::max((noThreads)*(m_parts_per_thread),m_blocks_per_row));
    //join
    for(unsigned short thread_indx=0;thread_indx<noThreads;thread_indx++)
    {
        m_threads_array[thread_indx].join();
    }
//EDIT 
    inline ull m_singularity_checker(ull t_to_be_ckecked_with,ull 
    t_to_be_ckecked)
    {
            return (t_to_be_ckecked & (t_to_be_ckecked_with<<1)
             & (t_to_be_ckecked_with>>1) ) | (t_to_be_ckecked_with & 
    t_to_be_ckecked);
    }
```

Comment: If the threads don't interfere with one another (the tasks are fully independent) then check that the actually work load is significantly larger than the overhead of starting threads. It's not clear what you are doing exactly, so it's hard to say exactly what the problem is.

Comment: There is a bucketful of reasons why this can be the case.  A couple of the more generic include staring more threads than your hardware has, or `m_signularity_checker` doing something that can only be run sequentially (like allocating memory or a section protected with a mutex).  Without more code showing what you're trying we can't tell what your specific problems are.

Comment: "why does having more than one thread(parallel processing) in some specific cases degrade performance?" - Many, many reasons. Some are; 1) the overhead of creating and destroying threads outweigh the amount of work done in parallel in each thread. 2) the threads need to synchronise a lot and effectively run serially, so threads only add overhead. 3) *false sharing* and similar problems when threading badly kills the performance. 4) overcommitting the system with way more active software threads than available hw threads causes a lot of overhead doing context switches. 5) much, *much* more.

Comment: Another possible reason is taking measurements incorrectly.

Comment: i edited the post to include the missing function
@FrançoisAndrieux i think you might be right ,do you have any idea how to elegantly  measure/make sure of that(measure the processing and the context switching time separately )?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm i edited the post with the missing function,and ,unless i dont see it, the threads seem to be independent of each other

Comment: @JesperJuhl do you have any suggestion for best practices on how to detect which reason is killing the performance (giving that the thread are independent)

Answer (score 3):

> why does having more than one thread(parallel processing) in some specific cases degrade performance?

- Because thread creation has overhead. If the task to be performed has only small computational cost, then the cost of creating multiple threads is more than the time saved by parallelism. This is especially the case when creating significantly more threads than there are CPU cores.
- Because many algorithms do not easily divide into independent sub-tasks. Dependencies on other threads requires synchronisation, which has overhead that can in some cases be more than the time saved by parallelism.
- Because in poorly designed programs, synchronization can cause all tasks to be processed sequentially even if they are in separate threads.
- Because (depending on CPU architecture) sometimes otherwise correctly implemented, and seemingly independent tasks have effectual dependency because they operate on the same area of memory.  More specifically, when a threads writes into a piece of memory, all threads operating on the same cache line must synchronise (the CPU does this for you automatically) to remain consistent. The cost of cache misses is often much higher than the time saved by parallelism. This problem is called "false sharing".
- Because sometimes introduction of multi threading makes the program more complex, which makes it more difficult for the compiler / optimiser to make use of instruction level parallelism.
- ...

In conclusion: Threads are not a silver bullet that automatically multiplies the performance of your program.

---

Regarding your program, we cannot count out any of the above potential issues given the excerpt that you have shown.

Some tips on avoiding or finding above issues:

- Don't create more threads than you have cores, discounting the number of threads that are expected to be blocking (waiting for input, disk, etc).
- Only use multi-threading with problems that are computationally expensive, (or to do work while a thread is blocking, but this may be more efficiently solved using asynchronous I/O and coroutines).
- Don't do (or do as little as possible) I/O from more than one thread into a single device (disk, NIC, virtual terminal, ...) unless it is specially designed to handle it.
- Minimise the number of dependencies between threads. Consider all access to global things that may cause synchronisation, and avoid them. For example, avoid memory allocation. Keep in mind that things like operations on standard containers do memory allocation.
- Keep the memory touched by distinct threads far from each other (not adjacent small elements of array). If processing an array, divide it in consecutive blocks, rather than striping one element every (number of threads)th element. In some extreme cases, extra copying into thread specific data structures, and then joining in the end may be efficient.
- If you've done all you can, and multi threading measures slower, consider whether perhaps it is not a good solution for your problem.

Comment: Excellent list of reasons! I would suggest mentioning two more things: (a) concurrent access to a system resource could be much slower than sequential access to the same resource. For example, reading two files simultaneously could be somewhat slower than reading them one after one. (b) Resource starvation. Processing N tasks simultaneously will likely take N times more resources. This could lead to all kind of things: exceeding the cache capacity and cache misses, swapping some pages to disk.

Comment: Regarding "finding issues", you may want to mention [ThreadSanitizer](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ThreadSanitizer.html) as well as using a profiler (like [perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)).

Comment: Thanks alot for you answer mate,i edited the question to include the missing code, anyway,i think it might be the false sharing point.
do you have any suggestion on a tool/method for debugging my situation (and i am sure the many more to come)?

Answer (score 1):

Using threads do not always mean that you will get more work done. For example using 2 threads does not mean you will get a task done in half the time. There is an overhead to setting up the threads and depending on how many cores and OS etc... how much context switching is occurring between threads (saving the thread stack/regs and loading the next one - it all adds up). At some point adding more threads will start to slow your program down since there will be more time spent switching between threads/setting threads up/down then there is work being done. So you may be a victim of this.

If you have 100 very small items (like 1 instruction) of work to do, then 100 threads will be guaranteed to be slower since you now have `("many instructions" + 1) x 100` of work to do. Where the "many instructions" are the work of setting up the threads and clearing them up at the end - and switching between them.

So, you may want to start to profile this for yourself.. How much work is done processing each row and how many threads in total are you setting up?

One very crude, but quick/simple way to start to measure is to just take the time elapsed to processes one row in isolation (e.g. use `std::chrono` functions to measure the time at the start of processing one row and then take the time at the end to see total time spent. Then maybe do the same test over the entire table to get an idea how total time.

If you find that a individual row is taking very little time then you may not be getting so much benefit from the threads... You may be better of splitting the table into chunks of work that are equal to the number of cores your CPU has, then start changing the number of threads (+/-) to find the sweet spot.  Just making threads based on number of rows is a poor choice - you really want to design it to max out each core (for example).

So if you had 4 cores, maybe start by splitting the work into 4 threads to start with. Then test it with 8 if its better try 16, if its worse try 12....etc...

Also you might get different results on different PCs...